# Bitmap to byteArray without compress

Tags: android, bitmap, compression, byte

I am aware of the code below

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

but the issue is that this code reduces the image quality so much that it is unrecognizable how can i avoid

```
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CompressFormat.PNG, where the compress quality doesn't matter, its always lossless as described in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream))

Comment: both JPEG and PNG are not working for me image quality is very low I am using Lollipop version by the way

Comment: Are you sure that the input image is of high quality?

Comment: yes my picture is captured from 8 mega pixel camera

Answer (score 0):

```
 array = new byte[w*h*4];
 Buffer dst = ByteBuffer.wrap(array);
 bmp.copyPixelsToBuffer(dst);
```

Comment: this one just gives us the pixels but when we want to get the image back with bitmapFactory.decodeByteArray it returns null